# Vend Api create or update product returns 500 error

Tags: php, curl, yii

I need to add product to my vend account via Api, but it seams not working.
I am using Yii2 for developing, I have send request with Curl and Yii request objects.

**Curl request**

```
$ch = curl_init() ;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $vend_api ) ;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST" ) ;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $product ) ;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Bearer '.$user['token'] ) ) ;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ) ;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false ) ;
$result = curl_exec( $ch ) ;
```

**Yii2 Request**

```
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->createRequest()
    ->setMethod('post')
    ->setUrl($vend_api)
    ->addHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $user['token']])
    ->setData($product);
   ->send();
```

Both returns 500 internal server error of Vend

[image]

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: There is no errors in my log files, there is only 200 status request to my action

Comment: Have you printed $response->statusCode and $response->data to get some more clues?

Answer (score 0):

Not much I can do to help without the actual URL.
The following will get the request and response headers along with the `curl_getinfo()`
I replaced `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST" )` 
with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`

Sometimes a script will purposely return a 500 if it does not like how the request looks.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$ch = curl_init() ;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $vend_api ) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $product ) ;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Bearer '.$user['token'] ) ) ;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ) ;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false ) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$result = curl_exec( $ch ) ;
if (curl_errno($ch)){
echo 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  $info = rawurldecode(var_export(curl_getinfo($ch),true));
  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $responseHeader= substr($result,0,$skip);

echo "....$info\n$responseHeader\n================\n";
echo substr($result,$skip);
}
```